# Gutenberg custom column block development

Tags: gutenberg-blocks

I am building a Gutenberg block with the following requirement. It is already working in the live site as a classic `shortcode` but now I need to transform the same into a block.

- The block will have two columns.
- Other blocks (both native and custom which I have already developed) can be added in both columns.
- I need to add separate attributes to separate columns so that they render like `data-span="4"` with the left column and `data-span="2"` with the right column or vice versa.

I created a custom `JSX` layout to render the block inside editor with two columns and added `<InnerBlocks>` in each,i.e. I had two `<InnerBlocks>`. But multiple `<InnerBlocks>` is not allowed so I had to discard that.

**I first tried this**

```
...
save: function ( props ) {
   return(
     <div className={props.className}>
       <div className="column-container">
          <div className="left-column">
             <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ [ 'core/paragraph', 'core/image', 'core/list' ] } />
          </div>
          <div className="right-column">
             <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ [ 'core/paragraph', 'core/image', 'core/list' ] } />
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   );
}
```

**Next I tried the following**

```
...
edit: function( props ) {
   <div className={props.className}>
      <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ [ 'core/columns', 'core/paragraph' ] } />
   </div>
}
```

The above let me add a column block and then inside each column. I am able to add other blocks including my custom blocks as well. I don't know how to put those above attributes (`data-span="x"`) for each of the columns added by the native `column` block.

**The rendered output looks like this (in live site)**

```
<div class="hall-columns">
   <div class="hall-column" data-span="4">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei vim persequeris liberavisse.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="hall-column" data-span="2">
     <p>
        <img class="alignnone wp-image-338" src="http://local.hall.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/book.jpg" alt="" width="322" height="182" />
     </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am searching for the last 3 days but unable to find any suitable article/thread which may show me some light.

Comment: Why you need those `data-span` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

There already is an option for that in Gutenberg. You first need to create a group. Then inside the layout add columns after choosing that group. Then you have to increase the column value.

[image: column image screenshot]